# Why is Pandas Read_JSON returning DataFrame with only one column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file that is formatted as follows (json_test.json):

```
{"Col1;Col2;Col3;Col4;Col5":{"0":"value;value;value;value;value","1":"value;value;value;value;value","2":"value;value;value;value;value","N":"value;value;value;value;value"}}
```

To me, this looks like the orient "columns" that pandas specifies in their documentation:
'columns' : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}

However, running my json through pd.read_json only returns 1 column with 4 rows.

I.e.:

```
df2 = pd.read_json("data\json_test.json")
df2.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4 entries, 0 to N
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                    --------------  ----- 
 0   Col1;Col2;Col3;Col4;Col5  4 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 64.0+ bytes
```

[image: df2 result]

Can anyone help me understand what is going on here, and how to properly read in this json file? I am not really familiar with json and most examples I've seen online are for very standardized json formats.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you create the dataframe? By reading values from CSV file? Maybe you forgot to specify `;` as separator.

Comment: @AndrejKesely The default behavior of read_json is to create a dataframe. Otherwise I'm not reading anything from a CSV...

Comment: But how this Json was created?

Comment: I have no idea, @AndrejKesely -- the json file was given to me as is.

Comment: I don't think `"Col1;Col2;Col3;Col4;Col5"` represents five different columns, since everything is inside double quotes, they'll be treated as a single value for JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have JSON as the overall structure
- within the JSON keys and values you have semi-colon delimited pairs
- this can easily be fully decoded by

  1. initailise a data frame with `pd.DataFrame()` with the JSON
  2. expand the delimited keys and values using `split(";")`
  3. convert these **lists** into **pd.Series** to then have a dataframe with columns and values

```
d = {"Col1;Col2;Col3;Col4;Col5":{"0":"value;value;value;value;value","1":"value;value;value;value;value","2":"value;value;value;value;value","N":"value;value;value;value;value"}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df2 = df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda s: pd.Series(s.split(";"), index=df.columns[0].split(";")))

df2
```

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | value | value | value | value | value |
| 1 | value | value | value | value | value |
| 2 | value | value | value | value | value |
| N | value | value | value | value | value |